# Issues running Angular tests in CI

Tags: angular, docker, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci, karma-runner

We're seeing a few issues with running our unit tests on our Angular project. Some of them are random and sporadic, others are continual, but we don't know if some of the issues are causing the others.

There are three main issues that we're seeing:

1. Sporadic test failures with the error message of:

```
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
```

These are strange, as the tests that fail are always different, but more importantly, they're never `async` tests. One example is:

```js
it('should call api when filter by Status', () => {
  component.selectedStatus = { value: 'Active' };
  component.selectedYear = { value: 0 };

  const query: query = {
    Status: component.selectedStatus.value,
    Year: component.selectedYear.value
  };

  spyOn(queriesService, 'load')
    .withArgs(component.param1, component.param2, query);
  component.onFilter();
  expect(queriesService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The error mesage also doesn't explain *what* function didn't complete correctly, so that's helpful.

2. Duplicate test runs (most tests are executing twice, but not every test, and not the same tests every time, but this is hard to confirm) (notice the `Executed 791 of 427` test line):

```
Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64): Executed 791 of 427 (2 FAILED) (3 mins 5.047 secs / 6 mins 4.605 secs)
TOTAL: 2 FAILED, 789 SUCCESS
1) should call api when filter by Status
     FundClientQueriesComponent
     Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    at <Jasmine>
2) should call api to delete query
     FundClientQueriesComponent
     Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
    at <Jasmine>
TOTAL: 2 FAILED, 789 SUCCESS
```

3. Timeouts when attempting to launch Chrome headless:

```
19 03 2021 11:26:15.283:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.9 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
19 03 2021 11:26:15.300:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
19 03 2021 11:26:15.321:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
19 03 2021 11:27:19.268:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
19 03 2021 11:27:28.603:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start ChromeHeadless again (1/2).
19 03 2021 11:28:25.545:INFO [Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket o_anOsdVys3P6a22AAAA with id 92253956
19 03 2021 11:28:29.105:INFO [Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.90 (Linux x86_64)]: Disconnected browser returned on socket 0m01E138U6uvEK44AAAB with id 92253956.
```

All tests are run using the following command: `ng test --watch false --code-coverage`.

The Chrome timeout issue occurs locally on some developer workstations (some work, some don't). The test count is correct, and all tests pass in every run.

Our tests are run in CI on GitLab shared runners, using the `trion/ng-cli-karma` docker image, with the following pipeline block:

```yaml
build-angular-test:
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma
  stage: build
  script:
    - export PATH=$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
    - npm ci
    - ng test --code-coverage --watch false
```

We've tried generating a brand new Angular application under the same version (10.2.x), with the same pipeline definition and none of these issues appear. The `ChromeHeadless` browser launches correctly, and within the timeframe (without a timeout) and the test count is correct. Copying the `karma.conf.js` file from this application into our own, but the same problems appear (our `karma.conf.js` file is below)

We've tried running the tests on a bare Unix machine, no through Docker, and the tests run successfully (`ChromeHeadless` launches first time, test count is correct, no `async` timeout errors).

We've tried enabling the `logLevel` to `config.LOG_DEBUG`, but that doesn't appear to provide anything helpful out of additional configuration output at the start (the logging for the test running still appears the same).

I've noticed that running locally I see the message of "Starting browser ChromeHeadless", but the build then condintues. Is it possible that the build is running longer than the timeout, and is it possible to configure the
`ng test` to wait for the build to complete before launching the browser?

We're a bit lost as to where to even start investigating. Is this an issue with Angular itself? Karma or Jasmine? GitLab and it's shared runner infrastructure? Could the issue be the base Dockerfile configuration?

For reference, our `karma.conf.js` file is here:

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    captureTimeout: 120000,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'], // change ChromeHeadless into Chrome to see result in Chrome browser
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    }
  });
};
```

UPDATE: As requested, a full spec file (with renamed components/services) including the `beforeEach()` sections is below. Note that we are undergoing a process of replacing `async` with `waitForAsync` as well (as `async()` is deprecated).

```js
describe('FooComponent', () => {
  let component: FooComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;
  let router: Router;
  let fooService: FooService;
  let BarService: BarService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooComponent, FundBannerTestComponent, BSBPipe, NumberPipe],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        DropdownModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        InputTextModule,
        FormsModule,
        ScTableModule,
        SharedModule,
        ScFormsMockModule
      ],
      providers: [
        DatePipe
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fooService = TestBed.inject(FooService);
    barService = TestBed.inject(BarService);
    spyOnProperty(barService, 'barDetail', 'get').and.returnValue({ Site: { Code: 'sabc' }, Bar: { BarCode: 'fabc' } });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call api when filter byYear', () => {
    component.selectedYear = { value: 2020 };
    component.selectedStatus = { value: '' };

    const query: FooQuery = {
      Status: component.selectedStatus.value,
      FinYear: component.selectedYear.value
    };

    spyOn(fooService, 'load').withArgs('sabc', 'fabc', query);
    component.onFilter();
    expect(fooService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: I once had something similar, turned out one of my `(done) => {}` parameters was never called (`done()` after the test). This resulted in a weird error somewhere else. Might this be the problem somewhere?

Comment: Are you able to share a full test that fails including the beforeEach function?

Comment: @OwenKelvin I've updated the question with an example of this.

Comment: Thanks @Randy, we're trying to identify any of those that could be a problem as well.

Comment: The image provides an environment to launch the regular (headful) chrome browser in an isolated environment. The issue you are experiencing could point towards a problem launching chrome, therefore the timeout.